# How to get a single result from a basic PHP function

Tags: php, function

Here is a PHP function :

```
public static function getMap($maps, $class = '')
    {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $html = '<div class="jsDivCenter">';
        if(count($maps)){
            
            foreach ($maps as $key => $value) {
                
                if($value[0] !== '' || $value[1] !== ''){
                    
                $sql = "SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->joomsport_maps} WHERE id=".intval($key);
                if($wpdb->get_var($sql)){
                    if(JoomsportSettings::get('partdisplay_awayfirst',0) == 1){
                        $home_map = $value[1];
                        $away_map = $value[0];
                    }else{
                        $home_map = $value[0];
                        $away_map = $value[1];
                    }
                    $html .= '<div class="jsScoreDivMap '.$class.'">'.$home_map.JSCONF_SCORE_SEPARATOR.$away_map.'</div>';
            
                }
                }
            }
        }
        

        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
```

Here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
        
        if ($rows->lists['maps'] && count($rows->lists['maps'])) {
            echo "<center><font color='blue'>Maps</font></center>";
            echo jsHelper::getMap($rows->lists['maps']);
        }
        ?>
```

I would like this PHP code to display only the "map" with ID = 4 and not the entire list. How to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the array structure of `$rows->lists['maps']` ? Does it contain the map ID's?

Comment: Well, I can't tell for sure right now. Would it be possible to get the 2 options ? Many thanks John.

Comment: in your php code add this: `print_r($rows->lists['maps']);` and then copy and paste its output into your question so I can see.

Comment: Array ( [4] => Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 22 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => -3 [1] => 3 ) )

Comment: Do any of those numbers in that array look like your map ID?

Comment: Yes, the [4] .. :)

Comment: I posted an answer, please let me know if it worked

Comment: Basically, I'd like to display "25 - 22", the [4] Array only.

Currently, it's displaying "25 - 22  -3 - 3" because of the "lists" I believe. (Array [4] and [5])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
<?php
        
        if ($rows->lists['maps'] && count($rows->lists['maps'])) {
            echo "<center><font color='blue'>Maps</font></center>";
            $maparray = $rows->lists['maps'];

            if (!empty($maparray[4])){
                 $newmap[4] = $maparray[4];
                 echo jsHelper::getMap($newmap);
                }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: @Coucouyou hope you are still here, I made an edit to the answer which should be more stable in case of some weird events. I recommend using the updated code. Thanks